# Android ANR , Service is locking main GUI Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-anr-dialog, futuretask

Im starting several background services that take a while to configure due to web services calls, etc...

However Im starting these services via AsyncTask in order to avoid locking the main thread & GUI, however the GUI stills becomes locked.

Im using AsyncTask to call start a BluetoothService in my Activity onCreate():

I only included relevant lines of  code:

```
 //asynchronously - start the bluetooth service
            new BluetoothServiceStart().execute();
```

**Then in the BluetoothServiceStart service class, Im using Callable & Future  task to get bytes from a web service:**

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // stop the service when the notification bar is pressed
        if (intent != null && ACTION_STOP_SERVICE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping bluetooth service...");
            broadcastServiceState(false);
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        // in case of attempting to restart while already running
        clearSubscriptions();

        Util.logToast(this, TAG, "Bluetooth service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, Util.DEBUG);
        setupNotification();


        // find and load JSON config file
        loadDevices();
}

   /**
     * Gets the UUIDs of devices to connect to from the bluetooth JSON file.
     */
    private void loadDevices() {
        devicesLoaded = false;


        Byte [] bytesFromWebService = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {

            if (ConnectivityMonitoring.hasNetwork()) {
                //lets get the path of rest service that has the config file
                String address = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.address);
                String configuration_restful_port = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.rest_port);
                String client_name = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.client_name);
                String protocol = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.protocol);
                //construct bluetooth config path
                String bluetooth_config_path = NgfrApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.bluetooth_path);
                url = new URL(protocol + "://" + address + ":" + configuration_restful_port + bluetooth_config_path + client_name);
                //lets execute an FutureTask (async task with a result, that blocks until result is returned).
                ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Log.i(TAG, "making call to URL:" + url.toString());
                Future<byte []> future = exService.submit(new CallWebServiceAndGetBytes(url));
                bytesFromWebService = Util.toObjects(future.get());
            }
            if (bytesFromWebService != null) {
                devices = readDeviceConfigFromWebService(bytesFromWebService);
                Log.i(TAG, "Loaded configuration from URL:" + url.toString());

            } else {
                // read in the device UUIDs from the file
                is = Util.scanForJson(getString(R.string.file_path), getString(R.string.bt_config_file));
                devices = Util.readJsonStream(is, localConfigReadFunc);
                Log.i(TAG, "Read config file from PATH:" + getString(R.string.file_path)+getString(R.string.bt_config_file));
            }
            if (devices != null) {
                if (devices.size() < 1)
                    Log.w(TAG, "No devices to load!");
                devicesLoaded = true;
            }

            // devices successfully loaded
            if (devices != null && devicesLoaded) {
                Log.d(TAG, "" + devices.size() + " BLE device IDs retrieved");
                Log.d(TAG, "Devices: " + devices.toString());
            }

            // failed to load devices or find the JSON file
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load devices! Creating empty list...");
                devices = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to locate bluetooth config file: " + getString(R.string.bt_config_file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error reading json file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }//end loadDevices
```

Im getting an ANR & later crash.

Android Thread dump:

"main@4817" prio=5 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks main@4817
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2135)
      - locked <0x1a72> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:450)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
      at ngfr.wams.controller.core.services.RuleEngineService.loadRules(RuleEngineService.java:358)
      at ngfr.wams.controller.core.services.RuleEngineService.updateRules(RuleEngineService.java:462)
      at ngfr.wams.controller.core.services.RuleEngineService.onCreate(RuleEngineService.java:131)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3542)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java:-1)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

The error line points to `future.get()`.

**I understand that the `future.get()` blocks, which is intended behavior in order  to wait for the web service to return the bytes otherwise in low network connectivity/bandwidth situations the code will continue to execute and miss the network response & data.**

The `future.get()` blocks the Service, however since the BluetoothService is started using BluetoothServiceStart AsyncTask, then why is the UI blocked???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common mistake to assume, that a service is running on another thread than the starting activity. It will run on the main thread as well as stated here: [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.

The `startService` call will not change this behaviour, even if you call it in an `AsyncTask`. So if you want to reanimate your app, you should create a thread inside of your service, which is not blocking the service, thus not blocking the main thread.

Note that `IntentServices` offload the task to a worker thread but automatically stop when there is no further work to do.

> Clients send requests through Context.startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Maybe this is not what you want with a bluetooth service.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle methods always run on the man application loop, since the system creates the Service object for you.  So, it's onStartCommand won't run on a background thread like you intend.  If you want the Service to run on a background thread, use an IntentService.